# Tee Suppressing Progress Bar in Shell Script

Tags: shell, tee

I'm trying to log a script in its entire form using tee. Part of the script involves downloading files which which feature a progress bar to track the percentage downloaded and I've noticed this progress bar no longer appears on the terminal after using tee to log the whole script.

Is there a workaround for this to get the progress bar to once again display on the terminal?

Comment: Most software turns off interactive features (such as progress bars) when output is to a pipe rather than a TTY. That's generally a good thing -- you'll find your logged file to be near-incomprehensible if you turn the TTY back on if the progress bar implementation is at all fancy. So... are you *sure* you want it?

Comment: If you're sure, though -- see EmPTY: http://empty.sourceforge.net/

Comment: ...as I recall, there should also be a similar tool for faking a TTY shipped with Expect.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. is there any way I can simultaneously have interactive features on for the terminal and off when piping to a file (or something similar to this effect)? this would be the most ideal because I'm not too keep on downloading tools to resolve this.

Comment: Only if the software were explicitly written to allow this, and I've rarely if ever seen anything that was.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, well-written programs with content such as progress bars suppress such interactive content when writing to a FIFO (or, more generally, to a FD without an associated TTY) to make their logs easier to read or parse, which is why piping to `tee` is having the effect that it is. (Programs which use stderr rather than stdout for their progress bars might be more resistant, disabling the bar only when stderr is a non-TTY display).

If you want to fake having a TTY, tools such as [EmPTY](http://empty.sf.net) can do this. However, this will mean that all the progress-bar-related cruft will end up in your log file, which can make it both large and difficult to read or parse.

Unfortunately, you can only have it both ways (progress bar to the TTY, non-bar content including stderr to a file) if the software you're running was explicitly written to allow that, which is rarely done if ever.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you want to see the progress bar anyway. ie: if your program is using tee, but it's actually running on an interactive shell.

To do that use `script` instead of `tee`

```
script -c 'yourcommand' <some_log_file>
```

This way you will be able to capture the output in a file and ALSO see the progress bar (like the current progress when docker is pulling images).

Documentation: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html

This is how I found out:
https://forum.restic.net/t/how-to-get-verbose-progress-updates-but-also-log-with-tee/2825/2